# Merging two XPathDocuments using XmlCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xslt, merge, xslcompiledtransform

I can't possibly be the first person to do this, it seems like it would be such a common practice to merge two documents using XSLT.  However, I can't seem to find a single example on the ol' interweb.

I have two XML documents that are being retrieved as strings of XML from SQL Server.  I want to use `XslCompiledTransform` to merge the two documents.  I know that `XslCompiledTransform` turns off the XSL `document()` function by default.  I have turned that on using `XsltSettings` when I create my `XslCompiledTransform` object.

My understanding about how to "add" the second document to the transformation is to use an `XsltArgumentList` and use the `AddParam()` method and add an `XPathNavigator` object:

```
XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xsltArgs.AddParam(
  (string)e.UserState + "s", "http://www.myuri.com/tabledata", 
  dataXmlDoc.CreateNavigator()
);
```

However any attempts at accessing the document that is added results in either an error or nothing returned. — C#:

```
XslCompiledTransform fieldToXhtmlTransform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
try
{
  UriBuilder xsltUri = new UriBuilder(
    Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, 
    Request.Url.Port, this.ResolveUrl("Transforms/address1.xslt")
  );

  XmlSecureResolver resolver = new XmlSecureResolver(
    new XmlUrlResolver(), new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)
  );
  fieldToXhtmlTransform.Load(
    xsltUri.ToString(), new XsltSettings(true, false), resolver
  );
}
catch
{
  //TODO: do something useful here. 
}

XPathDocument fieldSchemaXmlDoc = null;

using (MemoryStream fieldMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(
  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result.TableMetaDataXml)
))
{
  fieldSchemaXmlDoc = new XPathDocument(fieldMemoryStream);
}

XPathDocument dataXmlDoc = null;

using (MemoryStream dataMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(
  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result.DataXml)
))
{
  dataXmlDoc = new XPathDocument(dataMemoryStream);
}

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xsltArgs.AddParam(
  (string)e.UserState + "s", "http://www.myuri.com/tabledata",
  dataXmlDoc.CreateNavigator()
);    
XmlWriter transformedDataWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, writerSettings);
fieldToXhtmlTransform.Transform(
  fieldSchemaXmlDoc, xsltArgs, transformedDataWriter
);
```

XSLT - Only accesses the added document, not the document loaded with the transform.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:hlsschema="http://www.myuri.com/tableschema"
  xmlns:hlsdata="http://www.myuri.com/tabledata"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl hlsschema hlsdata xsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <p>
  <xsl:template match="hlsdata:Address1s">
    <xsl:for-each select="hlsdata:Address1">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="hlsdata:dr_id"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  </p>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<hlsdata:Address1s 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:hlsdata="http://www.myuri.com/tabledata"
>
  <hlsdata:Address1>
    <hlsdata:dr_id>12345678</hlsdata:dr_id>
  </hlsdata:Address1>
</hlsdata:Address1s>
```

I know I'm missing something obvious, but it is getting beyond frustrating.  I know the document gets added as a parameter, but I can't find an example of how to access a document loaded as a parameter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Keep in mind that the code above is a work in progress and is between two of hundreds of attempts to make it work so if something looks a bit odd, its probably because its between attempts.

Comment: I don't think that your XSLT would work at all in its current form. The `<xsl:stylesheet>` element does not allow `<p>` children

Comment: Tomalak, thanks for the reply.  Like I mentioned the above code extracts were between many attempts to get this to work successfully.  The <p> element was in there because at the point that I copied the xslt I was attempting to correct a "multiple root nodes" problem.  Using Martin's examples below I was able to get my code to work.  It took a little tweaking, but it is working.  Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a parameter in your stylesheet and then use that parameter.
Here is a simple example, the stylesheet looks as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:docs="http://example.com/2010/docs"
  exclude-result-prefixes="docs"
>
  <xsl:param name="docs:doc1" select="/.."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$docs:doc1/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The C# code looks as follows:

```
    string xml = "<root><foo>1</foo><foo>2</foo></root>";
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));

    XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
    proc.Load(@"..\..\XSLTFile1.xslt");

    XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
    xsltArgs.AddParam("doc1", "http://example.com/2010/docs", doc.CreateNavigator());

    proc.Transform(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<dummy/>")), xsltArgs, Console.Out);
```

This is a console application which for simplicity writes to Console.Out but you can of course use other outputs the Transform method allows.

That example then writes `<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>` so the input parameter has been processed.

So that should show you how to pass in a parameter that XslCompiledTransform sees as a node-set you can process with XSLT.

As for writing a stylesheet that merges two documents, please post two input samples and the corresponding result sample you want to create if you have problems writing that XSLT.

Comment: Martin,
Thank you for your assistance.  Your example worked perfectly.  I'm having some difficulty getting my code to work as well as yours, but I'm sure its just a matter of figuring out how to apply your techniques to my code.

Comment: Martin, I was able to massage your example to work with my xml, I needed to add the namespace to the elements, but I did get it to work.  Thanks again.