# HttpContext XML values in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Please Help me out.

In C# i set a context value as

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["xmlcontentholder"] = xDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.OuterXml;
```

and

by processing XsltArgumentList i send it to an XSLT file:

```
XsltArgumentList XsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
XsltArgs.AddParam("xmlcontentholder", "", "xmlcontent");
```

and i m transforming it

```
xsltCompiledTrans.Transform(xPathNav, XsltArgs, stringWriter);
```

In XSLT file i gave as `<xsl:value-of select="$xmlcontentholder" /><br/>12<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($xmlcontentholder)/ROW[1]/value" />34`

My output is

```
<ROW><value>1</value><value>2</value></ROW>
1234
```

Please explain me on this problem..

Comment: Please add details like what is the input file content and what is the output you are trying to get.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**: The [**`OuterXml`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml(v=VS.71).aspx) property is of type `string`, but in the XSLT transformation you are treating it as a node.

**Solution**: Pass to the transformation a node -- the C# parameter needs to be either an [**`XPathNavigator`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator(v=VS.71).aspx) (for a single node) or **[`XPathNodeIterator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx)** for a node-set.

**Therefore, use**:

```
xDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.CreateNavigator()
```

Comment: Thank You Dimitre Novatchev. Your ideas worked for me. you are awesome. I solved it.

I also referred to the post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365295/merging-two-xpathdocuments-using-xmlcompiledtransform

Stackoverflow is superb.